# relative clause and pronoun , object and complement

Tags: relative-clauses, relative-pronouns

I learned that in relative clauses, the relative pronoun acts as a subject or an object or a complement.

> Red is the color which we painted the wall.

Is this sentence grammatical?
Paint is a verb that should be followed by a object and a complement, so I think **red** act as a complement in this relative clause, therefore the sentence should make sense. Is that right?

> The teacher doesn't like the student whom we elected class president.

Elected is a verb that should be followed by two objects, so in this clause, even though we have one object **class president** already, one object is still missing , and **whom** represents the missing object, is that right?

> This is a lesson which the students are eager to learn.

I am slightly confused with this one, inside the relative clause
Subject : **the students** , verb : **are** , complement(adj) : **eager**
**to learn** acts as an ***adverb*** to modfiy the complement(adj) **eager**,
so the clause itself seems complete already, so what does the relative pronoun **which** represents here ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Which* points to the complement (more precisely, the direct object) of *to learn*: The students are eager to learn [this lesson]. *To learn [this lesson]* is the complement of the adjective *eager*.

(Yes, adjectives have complements too!)

Here's a tree diagram which illustrates the complexity of the structure:

[image]

*Which* refers backward to *a lesson* and forward to the missing object of *learn*. *Students* is the implicit subject of the infinitival clause which is the complement of the adjective *eager*.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know adjective have complements too, I used to think it should be an adverb. And for the first and second sentence, are my knowledge correct?

Comment: @Kathy Yes, your first two parses are correct, except that technically *class president* is an object complement rather than an object.

Comment: So inside the complement “to learn this lesson” there is another complement, which is “ this lesson”, then the clause sentence structure would go like S+V+C+C+C, is that legit ?

Comment: @Kathy It's a bit more complicated than that. I've added a diagram from [Miles Shang's website](http://mshang.ca/syntree/), based on this bracketed notation: [CLAUSE [SUBJECT [np This]] [PREDICATE [v is] [COMPLEMENT [np [^dp a lesson<a>] [RELATIVE*CLAUSE [RELATIVIZER_a which][CLAUSE [SUBJECT [np students<b>][PREDICATE [v are][COMPLEMENT [ap [adj eager][COMPLEMENT [INFINITIVAL*CLAUSE [SUBJECT_b (__)] [PREDICATE [^v to learn][OBJECT [np ___ <a>]]]]]]]]]]